# Date with Timezone?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using the default `Date()` constructor to get the current Date of the user.

At the time of writing this, it's 00:52, Monday (GMT) morning. When I trace the value of `date.getDay()`, I get `Sunday` printed.

Why does this happen? How can I set a timezone?

Cheers.

Comment: have you checked your computer to make sure the data is acutally set right (I could see myself making this silly mistake). Anyways have a read through [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) and see if it helps at all.

Comment: In case it helps, remember that getDay() starts at 0 = Sunday. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#getDay()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date.getDay()` will give you the day in *local* time. If you want universal time, use `Date.getUTCDay()`.